# can we use spring expressions (spel) in other annotations?

Tags: java, spring

I want to be able to do this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/#{handlerMappingPaths.security}/*")
public class SecurityController {
  etc

  //for instance, to resuse the value as a base for the folder resolution     
  @Value("#{handlerMappingPaths.security}/")
  public String RESOURCE_FOLDER;

  @RequestMapping(value="/signin-again", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String signinAgainHandler() {
        return RESOURCE_FOLDER + "signin_again";
    }
}
```

this doesn't appear to work now, am I missing something?

Comment: to clarify, the spel expression works just fine with the @value annotation for setting the value of "RESOURCE_FOLDER", but it won't work in the @RequestMapping annotation

Answer (score -3, accepted):

@Sean answered the question of whether spring supported this, but I also wanted to answer the question of just generally how not to duplicate configuration when using annotations. Turns out this is possible using static imports, as in:

```
import static com.test.util.RequestMappingConstants.SECURITY_CONTROLLER_PATH

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/" + SECURITY_CONTROLLER_PATH + "/*")
public class SecurityController {
  etc

  //for instance, to resuse the value as a base for the folder resolution     
  public String RESOURCE_FOLDER = SECURITY_CONTROLLER_PATH + "/";

  @RequestMapping(value="/signin-again", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String signinAgainHandler() {
        return RESOURCE_FOLDER + "signin_again";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way you can find out things like this is to have a look yourself. This is an example for eclipse, but it should work similarly for other IDEs:

First of all, make sure you have the sources of the spring libraries you are using. This is easiest if you use maven, [using the maven-eclipse-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/attach-library-sources.html) or using [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/).

Then, in Eclipse select `Navigate -> Open Type...`. Enter the type you are looking for (something like `RequestMa*` should do for lazy typers like myself). Enter / OK. Now right-click the class name in the source file and select `References -> Project`. In the search view, all uses of this class or annotation will appear.

One of them is [DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.determineUrlsForHandlerMethods(Class, boolean)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.html#determineUrlsForHandlerMethods%28java.lang.Class,%20boolean%29), where this code snippet will tell you that expression language is not evaluated:

```
ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(currentHandlerType, new ReflectionUtils.MethodCallback() {
    public void doWith(Method method) {
        RequestMapping mapping = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(
                                     method, RequestMapping.class);
        if (mapping != null) {
            String[] mappedPatterns = mapping.value();
            if (mappedPatterns.length > 0) {
                for (String mappedPattern : mappedPatterns) {
                    // this is where Expression Language would be parsed
                    // but it isn't, as you can see
                    if (!hasTypeLevelMapping && !mappedPattern.startsWith("/")) {
                        mappedPattern = "/" + mappedPattern;
                    }
                    addUrlsForPath(urls, mappedPattern);
                }
            }
            else if (hasTypeLevelMapping) {
                urls.add(null);
            }
        }
    }
}, ReflectionUtils.USER_DECLARED_METHODS);
```

Remember, it's called Open Source. There's no point in using Open Source Software if you don't try to understand what you are using.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but please save your disparagement, you have no idea what a poster has tried or not tried-

Comment: @chris True, and don't take this personally, either. SO answers are targeted at a larger audience than just the OP. I was making a general observation that was perhaps unjustified in your case

Comment: last line = pure GOLD.!!

Answer (score 2):

Answering in 2020: with current Spring versions, SpEL expressions can be used in `@RquestMappning` annotations.
They are correctly parsed.

**Inner details:**
Spring's `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` calls `embeddedValueResolver#resolveStringValue.`
JavaDoc of `EmbeddedValueResolver` states the following:

> StringValueResolver adapter for resolving placeholders and expressions
>   against a ConfigurableBeanFactory. Note that this adapter resolves
>   expressions as well, in contrast to the
>   ConfigurableBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue method. The
>   BeanExpressionContext used is for the plain bean factory, with no
>   scope specified for any contextual objects to access.
>
> Since: 4.3

This means both regular placeholders (e.g. `${my.property}`) and SpEL expressions will be parsed.

Note that because regular placeholders are parsed first and SpEL expressions are parsed later, it's even possible to set the value of a property to a SpEL expression. Spring will first replace the placeholder with the property value (SpEL expression) and then parse the SpEL expression.