# How to version my API with Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, api, spring-mvc, version

For now, URLs of my API are for example:

```
/api/users
```

With Spring MVC:

```java
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
```

I would like to version this api:

```
/api-v1.0/users
```

The best would be to be able to use an SpEL in the `@RequestMapping` annotation, but [it is unfortunately not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3281978/1225328):

```java
@RequestMapping("/api-#{appProps['version']}/users")
```

What are the other options then?

Comment: 1. Code it hard.  2. pre-process your code (e.g. ant-replace/maven-filter...)  3. Extend DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping (but don't break it:)

Comment: @sp00m So you want to load the version from property file?

Comment: @minion This would be the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@RequestMapping resolves from property place holder values. So define a PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer like below.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties"/>
```

Then use the syntax like below.

```
@RequestMapping("/api-${version}/users")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with `@RequestMapping("/api-${version}/users")`.

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-placeholders for more info.