# Get parameter in custom annotation using SPeL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

I am trying to create a custom annotatin that will grab the parameter from a function based on the name provided.
For example:

```
@AuthzPreAuthorize(filterType = "CUSTOMER_NUMBER", filterKey = "#objectId", filterRole = "role")
    public ComplexOrder findComplexOrderPre(String objectId){}
```

should get the objectId parameter and pass it into the annotation before the function runs. The problem I am running into is when I try to parse the expression "#objectId"
`Expression expFilterKeyName = parser.parseExpression(expression); String objectId = expFilterKeyName.getValue(String.class);`
objectId is always null.

How do I pass objectId into the annotation with SPeL? I know using `args[0]` would work but I need this annotation to work with multiple methods that I don't know the parameters to. I have also tried doing approaches similar answers in [Get dynamic parameter referenced in Annotation by using Spring SpEL Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53822544/get-dynamic-parameter-referenced-in-annotation-by-using-spring-spel-expression) and [can we use spring expressions (spel) in other annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281978/can-we-use-spring-expressions-spel-in-other-annotations) but have not been sucessful.

My annotation aspect class:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AuthzPreAuthorizeAspect {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthzPreAuthorize.class);

    private final SpelExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @Before(value = "execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(authzPreAuthorize)")
    public void authzPreAuthorize(JoinPoint joinPoint, AuthzPreAuthorize authzPreAuthorize) throws Throwable {
        // Get the method arguments from the joinPoint
        Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();

        // Log the SpEL expression for debugging
        String expression = "#objectId"; //for testing
        //String expression = authzPreAuthorize.filterKey();
        logger.info("SpEL Expression: " + expression);

        Expression expFilterKeyName = parser.parseExpression(expression);
        String objectId = expFilterKeyName.getValue(String.class);

        logger.info("objectId: " + objectId);
        //do stuff with objectId...
    }
```

My service class where I call the annotation from (objectId is "100004545"):

```
    @AuthzPreAuthorize(filterType = "CUSTOMER_NUMBER", filterKey = "#objectId", filterRole = "'com.gfs:order.access'")
    public ComplexOrder findComplexOrderPre(String objectId){
        return new ComplexOrder(2.7, new Address("40000 main st", "NY", 55555), new Customer(objectId, "unit", "role"));
    }
```

I am expecting to get objectId in my annotation to be "100004545". I know using `args[0]` would work but I need this annotation to work with multiple methods that I don't know the parameters to.